# $f(x)=x^{{3}/{2}}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$. Continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f(x)=x^{{3}/{2}}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ on $(0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$. Continuous?

I'm trying to understand if this function will be  continuous at zero. I feel like it will be because the $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ will get to zero really fast as $x$ goes to zero to help handle the crazy oscillations. How do I make this rigorous?? Thanks!

Comment: $0\leq|x^{3/2}\sin(1/x)-0|\leq |x|^{3/2}\to0$ as $x\to 0$. So, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0=f(0)$.

Comment: It is also differentiable since $0\leq \left|\frac{x^{3/2}\sin(1/x)-0}{x}\right|\leq |x|^{1/2}\to0$  as $x\to0$. So, $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The function$\;\sin\frac1x\;$ is *bounded*...If you need more ask.

**On request**: Since $\;-1\le\sin\alpha\le 1\implies |\sin\alpha|\le 1\;$  for all $\;\alpha\in\Bbb R\;$ , we get that

$$0\le\left|x^{3/2}\sin\frac1x\right|\le|x^{3/2}|\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$$

applying the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Yeah, haha, would you please?, I'm not as well versed on the introduction to analysis stuff, only had 1 semester in a pretty weak course, so when stuff like this comes up in my measure theory class i'm like ugh.

Comment: While 1/x may tend towards infinity or negative infinity at x=0, sin of any number must be between -1 and 1. So while it will oscillate infinitely many times, sin(1/x) is bounded.